# CocoaPod Pods-HockeySDK Archive Error: Could not build module 'UIKit'

Tags: xcode5, cocoapods

This issue is driving me nuts, since I updated to Xcode 5.1.1  The weird thing is that this only occurs on my machine.  On my co-worker's installation of Xcode, the project archives successfully.

The project compiles and run successfully on my device.

Obviously there must be a config setting that is different on our systems, but I'm at a loss at where to look at

I've already checked the following:

- Remove ARM64 from my build setting's ARCHS (necessary due to a static library out product's using)

  - Removed (and re-addeed) UIKit.framework, as per this SO question

Here's my Podfile:

```
# Podfile

platform :ios, "6.1"
inhibit_all_warnings!

pod 'Reachability',  '~> 3.0'
pod 'KAProgressLabel', :git => 'https://github.com/Ranter/KAProgressLabel.git', :commit => '87f69fda798fd034fee1739f651d44761c37362b'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.14'
pod 'iToast', '~> 0.0'
pod 'AWSiOSSDK/S3'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.2'
pod 'AFNetworkActivityLogger', '~> 2.0'
pod 'CWPopup', '~> 1.2.4'
pod 'TheAmazingAudioEngine', '~> 1.3'
pod 'HockeySDK', '~> 3.5.0'
pod 'iCarousel', :git => 'https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel.git', :commit => 'fc618c721fcb9a682317ff198590c3a775033487'

post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.project.targets.each do |target|
        # Fixes issue with some pods not supporting ARM64
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
        end

        # Rename conflicting kBufferSize symbol in TheAmazingAudioEngine
        if target.name == 'Pods-TheAmazingAudioEngine' then
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                # Only add to Debug flags since Release inherits from it
                if config.name == 'Debug' then
                    config.build_settings['OTHER_CFLAGS'] ||= []
                    config.build_settings['OTHER_CFLAGS'] << '-DkBufferSize=TAE_kBufferSize'
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Thanks!